# Is there any way to change the properties of a Ms Access dialog Form when is Opened?

Tags: vba, ms-access, modal-dialog, ms-access-forms

Instead of using msgBox, I want to create My msgBox by form, "frmMsg".
"frmMsg" form has tow bottom, (Ok and No), and a label(lblMsg) for show message.
"frmMsg" property: Pop Up = Yes , Modal = Yes.

My Function for Open form is MsgInfo:

```
Public Function MsgInfo(Optional msg As String = "Are You Ok?", _
 Optional msgCaption As String = "Warning" ) As Boolean
    MsgInfo = False
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMsg"
    Form_frmMsg.Caption = msgCaption    ' Set Caption of Form
    Form_frmMsg.lblMsg.Caption = msg    ' Set Message of Form
    MsgInfo = MsgInfoResult     ' MsgInfoResult is Public Variable to store MsgInfo Result (Ok Bottom(True) or No Bottom(False) )
End Function
```

I used this in other Form, Example For delete Customer in Customer List ( Delete Bottom ):

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    If MsgInfo("Are You Sure Delete Customer?", , "Delete Customer!") = True Then
    ' Run SQL for Delete Customer
        Dim sqlDelete As String
        sqlDelete = "DELETE tblCustomer.*, tblCustomer.RowId " & _
                           "FROM tblCustomer " & _
                            "WHERE tblCustomer.RowId=[Forms]![frmCustomerList]![frmCustomerListSub]![RowId]"
         DoCmd.RunSQL sqlDelete
         Form_frmCustomerList.frmCustomerListSub.Requery
    End If
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

My Problem is After Open MsgInfo Form Before the user answers this, the Next commands (Sql) are executed.

To solve the problem, I changed AcWindowsMode in Function MsgInfo:

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMsg"
```

to

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMsg", , , , , acDialog
```

problem solved but There was another problem. The following commands are not executed:

```
    Form_frmMsg.Caption = msgCaption    ' Set Caption of Form
    Form_frmMsg.lblMsg.Caption = msg    ' Set Message of Form
    MsgInfo = MsgInfoResult     ' MsgInfoResult is Public Variable
```

please help me.

Comment: Make your choice. You can't both hold the code execution (while your dialog is active) and let it continue.

Comment: You can prepare a xml, json, or whatever string containing all your parameters for the dialog and forward it by using the `OpenArgs` parameter of the `OpenForm` procedure. Inside the form, during opening/loading it, you then will have to interpret your string and apply its informations to the forms properties you like to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no Expert in VBA or Any Programming Language neither am I a programmer by Profession. But , I've had my fair share in dealing with programming languages as a hobby.

In VBA, Any Code after the ,,,,,acDialog can't be run until the Form is closed so , What you need to do is find a way to Pass the Messages somewhere and have the form Retrieve it.

Create a Module to Pass the Message from the Function to the Form

```
'a Module named Module_gVar

Public MessageHeader as String 'Optional A Separate Text Box For a Header
Public MessageBody as String 'Main Body
Public MessageTitle as String 'Caption of the Form
Public MessageReturn as Boolean
```

This is the function to Call the Message box and Get a simple True or False Return

```
'Function To Call the MessageBox
Public Function CallMessageBox ( _
Optional msgHeader as string , _
Optional msgBody as string , _
Optional msgTitle as string)

Module_gVar.MessageTitle = msgTitle
Module_gVar.MessageHeader = msgHeader
Module_gVar.MessageBody = msgBody

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMessage",,,,,acDialog

CallMessageBox = Module_gVar.MessageReturn
'You can have the CleanUp on a Separate Function
'Since it's not a Procedure Variable it Isn't cleaned when it goes out of scope
Module_gVar.MessageTitle = ""
Module_gVar.MessageBody = ""
Module_gVar.MessageHeader = ""
Module_gVar.Return = False

End Function
```

Now for the Form itself.

```
'Retrieve the Strings
Private Sub Form_Current()

Me.[YourHeaderTextBox] = Module_gVar.MessageHeader
Me.[YourBodyTextBox] = Module_gVar.MessageBody
Me.Caption = Module_gVar.MessageTitle

End Sub

'A Button to Return a Value

Private Sub cmdYes_Click() ' Yes button

  Module_gVar.MessageReturn = True
  DoCmd.Close acForm,"frmMessage",acSaveNo

End Sub

Private Sub cmdNo_Click() ' No Button
  Module_gVar.MessageReturn = False
  Docmd.Close acForm,"frmMessage",acSaveNo

End Sub
```

You can Optimize the code from here on but it's the basic structure. I Recommend creating a Class Module in which you can retrieve strings , input strings , and call Forms.